# Can not login Magento admin page after move to my localhost

Tags: magento, admin, backend

I just move my Magento store to my localhost environment for testing use, I also using Git to maintain code, but after I move all the files to my local environment, I can't login my admin page, but I can still see my frontend pages, and the git, the database, seems works well.

When I type a wrong admin/password to my admin page, it still gives me "Invalid password".
But when I enter the right one, it just refresh the page and stay at the login page, nothing happens.

Does anyone has met this problem before? Has any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use `localhost` as host. Use `127.0.0.1` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently started using Magento for a project and came across this issue. I was left frustrated by the fact there are at least ten or more different workarounds suggested on the net and it took a bunch of trial and error to find one that did the job. Seemingly some workarounds work for some versions and not for others. No one explained why or how the problem occurs and the most popular solutions involve hacking the code base or using a different url, which shouldn't be necessary.

The cleanest solution I found for Community Edition 1.9.1.1 was editing two config values in the database:

```
update core_config_data set value = NULL where path = "web/cookie/cookie_path";
update core_config_data set value = 0 where path = "web/cookie/cookie_httponly";
```

The cookie path is actually NULL by default on a fresh installation but it must either be NULL or empty string.

The behavior arises because some browsers including Chrome have issues creating cookies with a *localhost* domain, this means that when Magento calls session_start() the session identifier cookie never gets created and as a result information can not be passed from page to page. The login procedure is actually successful but the next request doesn't know about it, hence why you get redirected back to the login screen. There are no errors because Magento doesn't account for this edge case as a possibility.

If you do not provide a domain value when creating a cookie on localhost then the browser has no problem with it. Unfortunately just setting *web/cookie/cookie_path* to NULL is insufficient, because Magento's configuration class resolves this as an empty string which is enough for a real domain to be set later in the code:

```
if (isset($cookieParams['domain'])) {
    $cookieParams['domain'] = $cookie->getDomain();
}
```

This method eventually uses the current HTTP host to resolve a real domain for the cookie, and the browser therefore wants nothing to do with it. However if we disable *web/cookie/cookie_httponly* then Magento will not perform this additional step, *$cookieParams['domain']* is unset and no domain gets passed as a session parameter, thus allowing the session cookie to be created and things to function as they should.

Note that any time you modify the database configuration you must delete the contents of /var/cache/ for the changes to be reflected.

If like me you don't want to have to comment out code, or even make configuration changes, then I created an extension which overrides the *getDomain()* method shown above and returns null if we are on localhost, this should be somewhat more future proof and result in no collateral damage.

http://www.mediafire.com/download/q39p4k95s5tlght/LocalCookie.zip

Answer (score 5):

Although this question is old, all the above answers did not work for me until I did one additional thing.

Follow the very helpful answers already posted (summary):

1. Change your base_url to `http://127.0.0.1/` for secure and unsecure path.
2. delete files in var/session and var/cache
3. alter your Varien.php file accordingly - depending on your version of Magento.

And then:

4. Finally, use `http://127.0.0.1/your/site/folder/name/index.php/admin`

It was the lack of the **index.php**/admin ( instead of using `http://127.0.0.1/site/admin` ).

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the contents of the cache folder /var/cache. Clear your browser cookies and try. Also, if you have copied down the database from your server, you may need to manually change the base urls (secure and non secure) as well as the cookie domain in the core_config_data table. Do this manually if you need to. e.g. web/unsecure/base_url with production value of http://www.mywebsite.com/ becomes "http://localhost/"

When ever I have had this it's because of this or cache. Ensure the cache folder is ignored in git hub if it's not already.

Comment: Also check the web/cookie/cookie_path in the same table.  If you were using a different base URL on one server to the next, this will have to be updated.  ' / ' alone is the root if not using a deeper path.

Answer (score 0):

1.you need remove the cache

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/session/*
```

2.change the domain form core_config_data

```
update core_config_data set value="http://127.0.0.1/" where path="web/unsecure/base_url";
update core_config_data set value="http://127.0.0.1/" where path="web/secure/base_url";
```

Answer (score 0):

do these steps : 
**1:** go through: **xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract** 

2: open **Varien.php** file 
**3:** make comment line number from **87 to 104** save it and try to login...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, but the fix was changing DB values:

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://127.0.0.1/example/' WHERE `path` = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://127.0.0.1/example/' WHERE `path` = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

Then in browser `http://127.0.0.1/example/admin`

Answer (score 0):

Same problem! I fix my problem after remove/replace static domain in core_config_data Table

web/secure/base_url

web/secure/base_link_url

web/secure/base_skin_url

web/secure/base_media_url

Answer (score 0):

For me, running it on IIS (I know, not officially supported):

Although other suggestions kind of worked I found the best solution was to enter a new A record for me domain like

> 127.0.0.1 local.example.com

Then in IIS add the binding

> local.example.com

to my site and it worked perfectly.

I found there were errors when actually trying to login to the customer account more than admin but believe it still applies.